# Key shortcuts in a web application

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I'm thinking about creating some keyboard shortcuts in my web application. But, most of the important shortcuts are already attached to the browser itself (like <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, etc...)

I've notice that the browsers don't use any <kbd>Shift</kbd> combination. But, <kbd>Shift</kbd> is already reserved to type uppercase letters, so, I think using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Key</kbd> combinations isn't a good idea.

**Are there some guidelines to write keyboard shortcuts on the web?**

Or, should I give up using it?

Answer (score 6):

If it's an internal application which a number of people use all day everyday, keyboard shortcuts can increase productivity immensely.

It doesn't matter too much what they are, because advanced users will learn them regardless. The safest ones to use, however, are the arrow keys. Also, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>ANY LETTER</kbd> are usually safe.

If it's an internal application, you also have the luxury (normally) of developing for a set browser/configuration/version. This can make it easier to map out key bindings also.